# Getting data frame form kafka using spark streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Hi I am new to spark thing. I have a use case of getting stream of data from kafka topics in windowed manner and then do analysis on top of it.
I tried below code and it is throwing error:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("TestKakfa").getOrCreate()

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "dummy_events") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()


query = df.writeStream.format('console').start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

I am getting below error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: 'null\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = b842e3ba-8584-4764-8068-cce6b8d7de5f, runId = edc960c5-e5ef-4493-b9a2-c9543e1d2a8d]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: INITIALIZING\nThread State: RUNNABLE'
```

Comment: Which spark version? Which Kafka version? Which Spark Streaming Kafka version?

Comment: Spark version: 2.3.1 
Kafka Version: confluent-5.0.0
Spark Streaming Kafka Version: spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0

Comment: So, Kafka 2.0... But you're using the wrong library for structured streaming, and make sure that the last 3 numbers matches the Spark version https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. fixed that issue.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question below with your solution in case it helps others